# Alternate ways of opening APK files on Android device?

Tags: android

I am trying to open up an apk to test an app in development on an old Android phone, and it doesn't open it automatically after downloading to the device (it offers to open it in Chrome or HTML editor). Is there another way to open it (through an app etc.) or might I assume because the Android device is old the apk might not open it?

Comment: I'm not sure you have .apk file - (it offers to open it in Chrome or HTML editor) means that you downloaded html page

Comment: If you have .apk it starts Package installer

Comment: Thank you. Yes even though I click on the apk file in email or on Google Drive, it keeps downloading in HTML format. Will have to figure out why.

Comment: I tried putting the apk file up on a website I have, and going to that URL. It still downloads as HTML even though it is a confirmed apk file. Not sure why.

Comment: try to use some file sharing service e.g. dropbox, Skype...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using AirDroid to download the apk via my computer and it worked beautifully!